# Spring custom parameter in application.yml

Tags: spring, yaml

I have a spring-boot application which has an `application.yml` file in `src/main/resources`.
I need to add my custom parameter for every spring profile like so:

```
spring:
   profiles: dev
   myCustomParameter: value
```

but `myCustomParameter` is highlighted and shows message 
`Unknown property 'spring.myCustomParameter'`

How can I overcome this problem ?

Comment: don't worry about it. Intellij has some issue with recognizing some properties sometimes. It no way affects your code execution

Answer (score 3):

IDE will work like this: Suppose you have User object, and it has an association with Profile object and Profile has `firstName` and `lastName` properties.

Then details of `profile` of `user` in yaml will like

```
user:
   profile:
       firstName: "Jhon"
       firstName: "DOE"
```

It's the same in your case: `profiles` is part of `spring` bean, but `myCustomParameter` is unknown for it.

In your case, if you need to access `myCustomParameter` value, then you required

```
@Value("${spring.myCustomParameter})
private String myCustomParameter;
```

but if you want to access `myCustomParameter` directly, you need to define it like:

```
 spring:
   profiles: dev

 myCustomParameter: value
```

Then you can directly access it:

```
@Value("${myCustomParameter})
private String myCustomParameter;
```